# Why does squaring $\sqrt{x+2}\ge x$ misses an interval?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

If I square both sides of $\sqrt{x+2}\ge x$ I get,

$$x^2-x-2\le0\quad\Rightarrow\quad (x-2)(x+1)\le0\quad\Rightarrow\quad x\in[-1,2]$$
But the interval $[-2,-1)$ should be included in the solution which is missed here. I'm wondering what's going wrong in the above approach that misses an interval?

Comment: $a\leq b$ implies $a^2\leq b^2$ for $a\geq 0$ and $b\geq 0$ only, but it's not true in general.

Comment: Because squaring doesn't preserve inequalities in general. For example when $x=-2$, then the inequality read as $0\geq -2$, while taking squares gives $0\geq 4$, which is false.

Comment: A handy tip is to record the domains and ranges (especially this one) of the initial functions, and compare them with the edited function(s), to check if you have stayed true to the question.

Comment: $-2<1.$ Is $(-2)^2<1^2?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt{x+2} \geq 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$ such that the LHS is well defined. Now, notice that for $x < 0$ we automatically have $$\sqrt{x+2} \geq 0 > x$$ whenever the LHS is well defined. So, all negative $x$'s such that LHS is well defined are part of the solution of the inequality. Since we are dealing with square root, $x+2$ needs to be nonnegative, i.e. the LHS is well defined for $x\geq -2$. We conclude that $$x\in [-2,0) \implies \sqrt{x+2} > x.$$

We are done with the case when $x < 0$, so let us assume that $x\geq 0$. Since both $\sqrt{x+2}$ and $x$ are nonnegative and squaring is **strictly increasing function** on $[0,+\infty)$, we have $$\sqrt{x+2} \geq x \iff \sqrt{x+2}^2 \geq x^2,\quad x\geq 0.$$ Your calculation then shows that it is necessary that $x\in [-1,2]$. However, since we assumed at the start of the case that $x\geq 0$, we only take the nonnegative part of $[-1,2]$, i.e. the solution of the inequality in this case is $[0,2]$.

To finish, we take the union of the solutions for both cases, i.e. the solution is $$[-2,0)\cup [0,2] = [-2,2].$$

---

In general, if you want to solve inequality $\displaystyle\sqrt{f(x)} \geq g(x)$, these are the steps:

1. Determine when $f\geq 0$ and denote that set with $\mathcal D_{f\geq 0}$. In your example $f(x) = x+2$, so $\mathcal D_{f\geq 0} = [-2,+\infty)$.
2. Determine when $g\geq 0$ and $g < 0$ and denote those sets with $\mathcal D_{g\geq 0}$ and $\mathcal D_{g < 0}$, respectively. In your example $g(x) = x$, so $\mathcal D_{g\geq 0} = [0,+\infty)$ and $\mathcal D_{g < 0} = (-\infty, 0)$.
3. Split into two cases, the first being $x \in \mathcal D_{f\geq 0}\cap \mathcal D_{g\geq 0}$ and the second being $x\in \mathcal D_{f\geq 0}\cap \mathcal D_{g < 0}.$ In your example $\mathcal D_{f\geq 0}\cap \mathcal D_{g\geq 0} =  [0,+\infty)$ and $\mathcal D_{f\geq 0}\cap \mathcal D_{g < 0} = [-2,0)$.
4. Solve the first case by squaring, since both sides are nonnegative, i.e.
   $$ \sqrt{f(x)} \geq g(x) \iff f(x) \geq g(x)^2,\quad x\in \mathcal D_{f\geq 0}\cap \mathcal D_{g\geq 0}.$$ When you get solution, don't forget to restrict it only to $x$'s belonging to this case. (Just like we restricted $[-1,2]$ to $[0,2]$.) Denote the set of solutions as $\mathcal S_1$. In your example $\mathcal S_1 =  [0,2]$.
5. The second case is automatic since for $x\in \mathcal D_{f\geq 0}\cap \mathcal D_{g< 0}$ we have $$\sqrt{f(x)} \geq 0 > g(x).$$ So, all $x$'s in this case are part of the solution, so $\mathcal S_2 = \mathcal D_{f\geq 0}\cap \mathcal D_{g< 0}$. In your example $\mathcal S_2 = [-2,0)$.
6. Take the union $\mathcal S_1 \cup \mathcal S_2$.

The reason why we have to split into cases is that squaring is not strictly increasing on whole $\mathbb R$, but only for nonnegative reals. This is important to remember in general, $a > b \iff a^2 > b^2$ works only for $a,b \geq 0$, and otherwise one needs to consider cases before squaring.

Comment: Also, compare this to inequality of type $\sqrt{f(x)} \leq g(x)$. The steps are the same, however, conclusions will be different (in particular in step 5.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very good explanation!

Comment: @Amirali, glad to help, you are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps all has been said already.

0)$\sqrt{2+x} \ge 0$ for $x\ge - 2;$

1)$\sqrt{2+x} \ge x$ for $x \in [-2,0];$

3)Consider $x>0$

We have for $a \ge b >0:$

$a^2\ge b^2$ $\iff$ $a \ge b$ (reasoning?).

Square the inequality where both sides are positive.

$2+x \ge x^2;$

$0 \ge (x^2-x-2);$

$0 \ge (x-2)(x+1);$

$x \in [-1,2];$

Recall we consider x>0, hence

$x \in (0,2]$

(formally $[-1,2]\cap (0,\infty)$).

4)Putting together 2) and 3):

$x \in [-2,0]\cup (0,2]=[-2,2],$ and we are done.

Comment: Technically, you can't take $[-1,2]$ in the last line since it came from the case where you assumed $x > 0$. I.e., even though $[-1,0]$ is a part of the solution, the reasoning you used to get it is wrong. It's still covered by the second case, but one can probably cook up an example where it wouldn't be.

Comment: Ennar. Yes, you are right, we can consider only $x >0$ in $[-1,2],$ i. e. $(0,2]$

Comment: Anyway, +1 for making a simple and short, yet complete answer. I somehow always end up with putting too much details in my answers.

Comment: Ennar thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss something here. when $x<0$ is the part of the solution because $$\sqrt {x+2}\geq 0 , x\leq0 $$  for clarifying try to second power of both sides $$0.1 >-0.5$$ so
$$(-\infty,o] \cap [-2,\infty) =[-2,0]$$ is the part of the  solution.
hope it can helps you